# Open a NCBI BLAST generated file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, blast, ncbi

Is there any way to generate PSSM matrix using PSI_BLAST so that I could read that matrix in python.

I have generated a Position Specific Scoring Matrix (PSSM) using PSI BLAST for protein sequences via "PSI-BLAST" .  I downloaded the file by clicking the PSSM in download options. However, my download file is in .asm format. I want to read this PSSM in python without losing any information.
Is there any way to open this blast generated file in python for further processing?